# What are your favourite game-specific coding gems?

Tags: algorithm

I'll start off with <s>John Carmack's</s> the Fast Inverse Square Root in Quake III:

```
float Q_rsqrt(float number) {

  long i;
  float x2, y;
  const float threehalfs = 1.5F;

  x2 = number * 0.5F;
  y = number;
  i = * ( long * ) &y;
  i = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );
  y = * ( float * ) &i;
  y = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );

  return y;

}
```

Comment: That's not really a question - at the very least, you might declare this a community wiki page...

Comment: Done, community-ized.

Comment: Screw that! just go with any and all code crafted by the great JC!

Comment: By the way, do note that there's a more accurate "magic number" to use in the fast inverse square root function: 0x5f375a86 ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#History_and_investigation )

Comment: Also note that it's not John Carmack's.

Answer (score 25):

mapValue function:

```
float mapValue( float inVal, float inFrom, float inTo, float outFrom, float outTo )
{
    float inScale = (inFrom != inTo) 
        ? ( ( inVal - inFrom ) / ( inTo - inFrom ) ) 
        : 0.0f;
    float outVal = outFrom + ( inScale * ( outTo - outFrom ) );
    outVal = (outFrom < outTo ) 
        ? clamp( outVal, outFrom, outTo ) 
        : clamp( outVal, outTo, outFrom );
    return outVal;
}
```

It takes a value, converts it to a proportion within a range, and then scales that relative to another range.  Like a double-lerp.

You can use it to normalise stuff:

```
float minDamage = 0.0f; float maxDamage = 300.0f;
float normalisedDamage = mapValue(damange, minDamage, maxDamage, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Or you can convert from one range to another:

```
float brakeStrength = mapValue(timeToCollision, 
    0.0f, 10.0f, // seconds
    1.0f, 0.2f // brake values 
    );
```

Notice in the second example that the out range is a different order to the in range.

It  doesn't look like much, but I use this little fella all over the place.

Answer (score 14):

I still can't believe how many times I've used the Pythagorean Theorem in my game code. To me, this simple formula is a gem in game development.

[image: a^2 + b^2 = c^2]
<sub>(source: [mathurl.com](http://mathurl.com/23fysej.png))</sub>

or

[image]
<sub>(source: [mathurl.com](http://mathurl.com/36qbdda.png))</sub>

and when only relative distance matters it can be used without expensive square root operation

[image]
<sub>(source: [mathurl.com](http://mathurl.com/244txpz.png))</sub>

Comment: Well to be honest, Pythagorean math is used ALL over game code, especially engines, such as physics code, rendering code, AI.

Comment: True. That's why it's a gem. ;)

Comment: An interesting variation is when you only care about the *relative* distances. Then you can skip the potentially expensive `sqrt` call and simply compute `distance2 = x^2 + y^2`.

Comment: @mmyers - Another wonderful thing: if you're working in x^2 space, the distance isn't just relative.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the relative distance bit. I have seen way too many unnecessary square root operations, just as people using A* when they should be using something less exact.

Answer (score 13):

The biggest one from me was reading about [Scott Bilas's GameObject system.](http://scottbilas.com/games/dungeon-siege/) Even though I don't use a database system like he does, it stopped me making 6 level inheritance trees and got me creating a component system which is much more manageable and reusable.

Answer (score 10):

I have to go with [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).  It was the first block of code that literally made my jaw drop.  *"You can do that?!?"*

Comment: Omg. The goggles! They do nothing!

Comment: The nested "do-while" inside the "switch-case" always makes me blink.
Even 20 years later...

Comment: Wow that's devil's smart!

Comment: -1. I don't like this one. Its not very useful today (you would use `memcpy` instead, if you want other people to be able to read your code)

Comment: @bobobobo: Read the code again. memcpy is not equivalent to Duff's device. There are modern arguments against using it, but the existence of memcpy is not one.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig why not? Memcpy will always be more readable, portable and probably more optimized.

Comment: @kaoD: Because memcpy is not equivalent to Duff's device - it doesn't matter how "readable, portable, and probably more optimized" it is if it doesn't do the same thing! Modern CPU pipelines will probably do better without Duff's device than with it because of branch prediction and instruction caching, but that has _nothing_ to do with `memcpy`.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig I completely missed your *memcpy is not equivalent to Duff's device* line. I'll have to look at the code again.

Answer (score 7):

A small C/C++ snippet from a game I helped write many years back:

```
(fill ? FillRect : DrawRect) (x, y, w, h, colour);
```

On my first game ([this](http://www.mobygames.com/game/wrath-of-earth)) I needed to access more than 1Mb of RAM, and, this being before the internet took off, I had no documentation for XMS and EMS that DOS apps used to access the extra RAM.

So, I ended up using a small 'backdoor' that featured in the 386 with regard to the segment registers. Normally, in real mode, the address was calculated as `seg*16+off` which limited you to 1Mb.

However, you could switch to protected mode, set up a segment to address 4Mb, switch back, and provided you didn't write to the segment register (which was OK since DOS only used the 8086 segment registers), you could access the whole 4Mb as a flat address space. Flipping back to real mode was necessary if you wanted to use the DOS services.

There weren't many DPMI extenders available either.

Comment: Almost works in C# (you need to declare a delegate type and insert at least one cast)

Comment: You mean with 32-bit addressing modes in real mode?  (i.e. requiring an address-size prefix).  Are you sure it was necessary to set up a segment descriptor, and that it didn't actually use segment register as the normal 16*FS + whatever?  I didn't think segments even had limits in 16-bit mode, just the base address (16 * their value), so couldn't you just set FS to something in 16-bit mode, and use `[fs:esi]` or whatever to access whatever you wanted?

Comment: I haven't tried this, or written any real code for 16-bit mode, just 32 and 64 bit asm, but it sounds weird.  Hmm, plausible though.  Modern CPUs definitely cache segment stuff internally, and only re-load those caches when you write to segment regs, so maybe that's how it kept the protected-mode base+limit (if that's actually what happened, and you weren't just using the 4MB starting at 16*FS).

Answer (score 5):

Here's one mentioned by Chris Crawford (and apparently used by Atari) which he calls 'A Graphics Trick':

```
LDA FIRST
EOR SECOND
AND CONTROL
EOR SECOND
STA OUTPUT
```

Read the [full article](http://www.erasmatazz.com/TheLibrary/JCGD/JCGDV4/GraphicsTrick/GraphicsTrick.html) for an explanation.

Comment: That link is now broken, so it would help to have an explanation here.

Comment: Thanks. He's gone and changed his website again. I updated the link.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I'm a big fan of the Mersenne Twister for predictable random numbers, especially if you need to create a several differently seeded instances of Rand

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister

Comment: Mersenne Twister is nice in the sense it is a good random number generator, but it's not particularly elegant or cool (or fast or easy to implement). For that, you might want to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_30.

Comment: WELL is generally better than MT for most uses.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_equidistributed_long-period_linear

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, people often underrate the power of design patterns in games. I've seen nearly every single GoF pattern applied with success to games.

Comment: One of the things I like about games programming is getting away from the standard GoF way of "correctness" and just focussing on pure lovely speed! That said, I've seen a lot of bad implementations of MVC in games which do more harm than good.

Comment: I think design patterns have their place. Not so much in games, though.

Comment: @blissfreak: There's nothing special about game programming that makes it some kind of wild west where patterns aren't common. They are ridiculously common and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866197/what-are-some-common-3d-game-patterns/866291#866291) are some examples.

Answer (score 4):

Math.atan2() is extremely useful (along with all of trig).

Comment: It is, gosh! I've done lots of 3D and never really needed it.

Comment: +1, it's the only way to go from x+y vector components to radians direction.

Comment: @RCIX: My point is that that transformation is unnecessary, i.e. (x,y) -> angle, there is a vector solution to any angle problem.

Comment: @Skizz. uh, ok? i don't see the connection between our posts...

Comment: I wouldn't really call a bare standard library function a "gem".

Comment: @RCIX: This is not a game-specific gem. Personally I've never needed it. It has trouble with dy=0. Generally, if you need this a lot, you've done something inefficiently.

Comment: @Skizz: Maybe for 3d, but i know of no other way to take a normalized vector and extract a radians direction value. Which as a good deal of value in 2D games.

Answer (score 3):

One of my favorites is the assembly language version of 'Life', and the whole description of optimizing it, in "[The Zen of Code Optimization"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1883577039) by Michael Abrash.

I'd recommend any of his books to anyone looking for coding gems.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the pythagorean gem above...
 I always tell people that for 3d programming they need only know: 
- a^2 + b^2 = c^2 
- soscastoa (sin = opposing side / sloped side, cos = attached side / sloped side, tan = opposed side / attached side)
 
- a . b = |a| * |b| * cos alpha
 
- a * b = |a| * |b| * sin alpha * unit vector
It can solve pretty much any 3d (or 2d) problem you encounter in game development - 4 rules.
 Sure, there are nicer ways, but this can solve em all - I should know, I'm a hack that based a career on em.

Comment: re:soscastoa I think most people know that as sohcahtoa (replacing 'sloped side' with the more specific, if admittedly more obscure, 'hypotenuse'). Flows off the tongue easier, and I think thus easier to remember.

Comment: I'll always prefer 'The Old Arab Sat On His Camel And Howled', since secondary school (high school age) it's been imprinted on my brain.

Comment: There's also "**S**ome **O**ld **H**ippy **C**ame **A**nd **H**ad **T**ripped **O**n **A**cid"